# Find and remove text in div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a rss-feed where every post ends with a link wrapped in a paragraph. I want it deleted.

Example:

```
<p>I want to keep this</p>

<p>I want to <strong>find</strong> and <a href="#">remove</a> this string</p>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this on the server-side with PHP or on the client-side with javascript? Do you want it removed or just hidden? Does each entry containing section that can be used to access last paragraph easier?

Comment: Any solutions are welcome. Hiding it or removing it doesn't matter. I've also got other feeds from other sources which makes the p:last solution useless.

Comment: Do you want the whole paragraph containing the link removed or just the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, deleting the last paragraph can be done like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p:last').remove();
});
```

If an RSS newsitem has its own class, like `class="RssRow"`, you could use `each()` to remove the last child for each row:

```
$('.RssRow').each(function() {
    $(this).find('p:last').remove();
});
```

Comment: You can write the last on `$('.RssRow').find('p:last').remove()` or even simpler `$('.RssRow p:last-child').remove()` or `$('.RssRow > p:last-child').remove()` if you only interested in the immediate children i.e. only the last paragraph of the row are hidden, not the last paragraph of a block within the row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with jQuery and it's always the last paragraph (and wrapped in div like you said in the title), then this might work.

```
$("div p:last-child").remove();
```

This finds last `<p>` in `<div>` and removes it.

How about this then?:

If you have structure like this:

```
<div id="feed1">
  <p>I want to keep this</p>
  <p>I want to <strong>find</strong> and <a href="#">remove</a> this string</p> 
</div>

<div id="feed2">
  <p>I want to keep this</p>
  <p>I want to <strong>find</strong> and <a href="#">remove</a> this string</p> 
</div>
```

Then you can delete each last paragraph containing a link with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
  $("p:last-child > a").parent().remove();
});
```

This would result to output:

```
I want to keep this
I want to keep this
```

Comment: I've also got other feeds from other sources where which makes the p:last solution useless. I want to search for that particular string and remove/hide it.